# Advanced calculus advice

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

If $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and there exists bounded sequence$\{x_n\}$ with $x_n \neq x_m,$ if $n \neq m$ and $f(x_n)=0, \forall n,$ then $\ \exists$ $x_o$ such that $f(x_o)=0$ and $f'(x_o)=0.$

May I know if my proof is correct? Thank you very much.

Proof: Since $\{x_n\}$ is bounded, there exists $M$ such that $x_n \in [-M,M], \forall n.$ By the sequential compactness theorem, there exists subsequence $\{x_{n_{k}}\}$ of $\{x_n\}$ such that $x_{n_{k}} \to x_o \in [-M,M].$ Since $f$ is continuous at $x_o, f(x_{n_{k}}) \to 0 = f(x_o).$

Since $f$ is differentiable, the function $h:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as $h(x)=\dfrac{f(x)-f(x_o)}{x-x_o}, x\neq x_o$ and $h(x_o)=f'(x_o)$ is continuous at $x_o.$  Hence, $h(x_{n_{k}}) \to 0=f'(x_o).$

Answer (score 0):

Perfect proof. You get full marks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your proof is quite correct.